# Kafka (0.10.0.1) Mirror Maker is not working, seems the process is running but is doing nothing

Tags: apache-kafka

I am facing a weird problem where my mirror-maker is able to mirror the topic name in the destination cluster but I am seeing no messages when I try to consume messages from it. Below is my configuration file –

```
Kafka version : kafka_10.0.1
All Certs /Keys are my organization issued certificate so no Error for SSL 

Source Cluster :
==============

Zookeeeper Properties
dataDir=/home/kafka/zookeeper
clientPort=2181
maxClientCnxns=3


Server Properties

broker.id=1
listeners= SSL://123.456.789.110:9092
advertised.listeners=SSL://123.456.789.110:9092
security.inter.broker.protocol=SSL
num.network.threads=3
num.io.threads=8
auto.create.topics.enable=true
ssl.client.auth=none
ssl.keystore.location=/etc/keys/keystore
ssl.keystore.password=test1234
ssl.truststore.location=/etc/CApath/trustedstore
ssl.truststore.password=test1234
ssl.enabled.protocols=TLSv1.2
log.dirs=/home/kafka/kafka-logs
zookeeper.connect=123.456.789.110:2181


 Kafka Up and Running . Log persistently logging in Source Cluster 

Target Cluster :
================
Zookeeeper Properties

dataDir=/home/kafka/zookeeper
clientPort=2181
maxClientCnxns=3

Server Properties
broker.id=1
listeners= SSL://234.456.789.110:9092
advertised.listeners=SSL://sl73easapd04.visa.com:9092
security.inter.broker.protocol=SSL
num.network.threads=3
num.io.threads=8
ssl.client.auth=none
ssl.keystore.location=/etc/keys/keystore
ssl.keystore.password=test1234
ssl.truststore.location=/etc/CApath/trustedstore
ssl.truststore.password=test1234
ssl.enabled.protocols=TLSv1.2
ssl.keystore.type = JKS
ssl.truststore.type = JKS
log.dirs=/data/visingh/kafka/kafka-logs
num.partitions=1
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
log.retention.hours=168
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
zookeeper.connect=234.456.789.110:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000

mm_consumer.properties :
bootstrap.servers=123.456.789.110:9092
exclude.internal.topics = true
auto.offset.reset=earliest
security.protocol = SSL
ssl.truststore.location=/etc/CApath/trustedstore
ssl.truststore.password=Test1234
ssl.enabled.protocols= TLSv1.2
ssl.keystore.location=/etc/keys/keystore
ssl.keystore.password=Test1234
ssl.truststore.type=JKS
ssl.keystore.type=JKS
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
group.id=test-consumer-group
client.id=mirror_maker_consumer
consumer.timeout.ms=50000

mm_producer.properties :
bootstrap.servers=234.456.789.110:9092
acks=1
batch.size=100
security.protocol = SSL
ssl.truststore.location=/etc/CApath/trustedstore
ssl.truststore.password=Test1234 
ssl.enabled.protocols=TLSv1.2
ssl.keystore.location=/etc/keys/keystore
ssl.keystore.password=Test1234
ssl.truststore.type=JKS
ssl.keystore.type=JKS
compression.type=gzip
```

I then started Mirror-Maker with the following command,This command run fines and topic  APP-logging  created in Target cluster but not logs on target Cluster.

bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.MirrorMaker --new.consumer --consumer.config config/mm_consumer.properties --producer.config config/mm_producer.properties --whitelist *

kafka MirroMaker Started but no logs on target Cluster.

I executed started another mirror maker command using topic name  with below command ,This command fails on target hostCluster

/bin/kafka-mirror-maker.sh --new.consumer --consumer.config config/mm_consumer.properties --producer.config config/mm_producer.properties --whitelist APP-logging

```
[2018-06-22 03:59:27,536] FATAL [mirrormaker-thread-0] Mirror maker thread 
failure due to  (kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$MirrorMakerThread)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid timestamp -1
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord.<init> (ProducerRecord.java:60)
    at kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$defaultMirrorMakerMessageHandler$.handle(MirrorMaker.scala:678)
    at kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$MirrorMakerThread.run(MirrorMaker.scala:414)
[2018-06-22 03:59:27,563] FATAL [mirrormaker-thread-0] Mirror maker thread exited abnormally, stopping the whole mirror maker. (kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$MirrorMakerThread)
```

Also run the ".*" including the quotes instead of just *.

bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.MirrorMaker --new.consumer --consumer.config config/mm_consumer.properties --producer.config config/mm_producer.properties --whitelist ".*"

```
 [2018-06-22 04:22:01,647] FATAL [mirrormaker-thread-0] Mirror maker thread failure due to  (kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$MirrorMakerThread)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid timestamp -1
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord.<init>(ProducerRecord.java:60)
        at kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$defaultMirrorMakerMessageHandler$.handle(MirrorMaker.scala:678)
        at kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$MirrorMakerThread.run(MirrorMaker.scala:414)
[2018-06-22 04:22:01,674] FATAL [mirrormaker-thread-0] Mirror maker thread exited abnormally, stopping the whole mirror maker. (kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$MirrorMakerThread)
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Try without `--new.consumer`